# Whats the difference between ぜひ and もちろん

Tags: words, nuances

Both mean of course, right?

I always traditionally used もちろん but I increasingly seem to see ぜひ.

When do you use each?

Comment: Can you explain the context you're talking about? I've never heard ぜひ used to mean "of course" or at least nothing where that's what I would first think of translating it to.

Comment: Something like-

今晩パーティへ行きますか？

もちろんパーティへ行くよ。

ぜひパーティへ行くよ。

Both seem to make sense to me

Comment: In case you're still having trouble, "今晩パーティへ行きますか？ もちろんパーティへ行くよ。"="Are you going to the party tonight? Of course *I'm* going to the party." and  "...ぜひパーティへ行くよ。"="...(I'd) love for you to come to the party." "ぜひ" might not be an exact match for the English "(I'd) love for you to (do)", but it's a polite way of encouraging someone to do something, as has been said previously in this thread :) I think "ぜひ" is also frequently used in a kind of "Make yourself at home (and do something)" way.

Answer (score 6):

I think you should think of ぜひ as "definitely" and of もちろん "of course". There may be a slight overlap in usage, but there's no overlap in nuance.

Comment: so either is OK and there's no difference?

Comment: もちろん違いがあります。ぜひ、もう一回読んでみてくださいね

Comment: definitely and of course mean pretty much the same.

Comment: sometimes, but not always. that distinction is I think what is being used to explain the answer to your question.

Comment: @user3408758: もちろん is "of course" in the matter-of-fact sense (e.g. "**Of course** you use sugar when baking!" or "**Naturally,** there are consequences."); it is not used as an affirmative response.  For further distinctions between もちろん and ぜひ, Khakionion has it covered reasonably well.

Answer (score 3):

ぜひ can be used in situations where you want to encourage someone to do something.

お腹がすいたら、ぜひフレッシュネスバーガーへ！

もちろん can be used in situations where you're replying to an inquiry.

お腹がすいた？もちろん、今朝から何も食べなかった

There are other contexts and usages, but that's one big difference.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to think of ぜひ as 'by all means' but with more of an encouraging undertone. Like the speaker is recommending/hoping you will do something.